# Junit5 assertions import

Tags: java, junit, junit5

So, I included Junit5 to my maven project and it kind of works, but anyway when I try to import assertions to a test I can only put `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*` without beign able to specify some precise assertion and in the code I have to write for example `Assertions.assertThrows()`.

Why can't I pick any specific assertion from the list?

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using `import static`?

Comment: Oh, it worked at once :) but why?

Comment: you probably need to look at doing auto static imports for the Assertions package in your IDE. To a search for your IDE online on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to import a single method, you have to use a static import, like this:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
```

Then you can simply use it like:

```
assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import specific assertions by using a `static` import:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
```

This works for me in eclipse…